# How to remove close button in Vungle SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, vungle-ads

I have integrated the VungleSDK in my game. I want to remove the "x" button from video ad showing to force the user to watch the  complete video. Here's a screenshot of my publisher settings:

[image]

This is my code to play Vungle ad video:

```
func playVungleAd(){
    let vSdk:VungleSDK = VungleSDK.sharedSDK();
    do{
        try vSdk.playAd(self, withOptions : [VunglePlayAdOptionKeyIncentivized: true])
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print("Error In video ad")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

It displays the following ad but with an "x" button.
How can I remove this close button?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please check what is the setting of your app? Is it in test mode or in active mode?

[image]

If the app is in test mode it is normal to see the close button. Please switch it to active mode and check it again. Also please allow about 30 minutes for the change to take effect.

If the app is in test mode, please share your Vungle app ID via tech-support@vungle.com and refer to this case and we will help you out looking into the case deeper.

Gabor